# How can I calculate large numbers in this operation in RStudio?

Tags: r, factorial

I am executing this operation and when the process gives me NaN,

```
    Choques<-c(1:10)
    print (Choques)
    pr<-0
    n<-3818
    p<-0.040633627

    for(i in Choques) {
    pr[i]<-(factorial(n)/(factorial(Choques[i])*factorial(n-Choques[i])))*p^Choques[i]*(1-p)^(n-Choques[i]) 
    print (pr[i])
    }
```

However changing the value of the variable n for a smaller number let's say 20, if it shows numbers, I would like to know if there is any method to change the NaN by numbers, I suppose the numbers are too big.

Comment: I removed `rm(list=ls())` since it is not related to your problem and could potentially annoy someone who incautiously ran your code to replicate your problem.

Comment: `factorial(3818)` returns `Inf`. You exceeded the limits of double precicision. You can look the numerical charactersitics up with `?.Machine`.

Comment: Why not just use `dbinom()`? That function doesn't literally compute huge factorials just to cancel them.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
factorial(n)/(factorial(Choques[i])*factorial(n-Choques[i]))
```

with

```
choose(n, Choques[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are computing binomial probabilities in a loop and accumulating them in a vector. You can drop the factorials and even the loop by just using the vectorized function `dbinom`. Your loop can be replaced by the single line:

```
pr <- dbinom(Choques,n,p)
```